# Making a list independent of itself(?)

Tags: python, list

I am experimenting with lists and was trying to get the following code segment to display:

```
----------
---hello--
----------
```

But to do this I need to get the 3 'listSmall's to be independent of one another. Is there a way to do this?

(

current output is of course:

```
---hello--
---hello--
---hello--
```

)

```
listSmall = ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-',]
listBig = [listSmall, listSmall, listSmall]
word = 'hello'
wordPosX = 3
wordPosY = 2

for i in word:
    listBig[wordPosY][wordPosX] = i
    wordPosX = wordPosX + 1

i = 0
while i != 3:
    print ''.join(listBig[i])
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: three helpers, irrelevant to the qustion:
 `wordPosX += 1` and `for v in listBig: print ''.join(v)` and `listBig[wordPosy][3:3+len(word)]=word`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `list` is mutable.

```
listBig = [listSmall, listSmall, listSmall]
```

makes `listBig` point three times to the same mutable list, so when you change this mutable list through on of these references, you will see this change through all the three.

You should make three distinct lists:

```
listBig = [ ['-'] * 10 for _ in range(3)]
```

no need for `listSmall` at all.

the whole code:

```
listBig = [ ['-'] * 10 for _ in range(3)] 
word = 'hello'
wordPosX, wordPosY = 3, 1
listBig[wordPosY][3: (3+len(word))] = word
for v in listBig:
    print(''.join(v))
```

Comment: You first line was 'This is because list is mutable'. How is that related to making listBig point three times to the same list?

Comment: @UtkarshSinha I have added some explanation. Is there something wrong?

Comment: Writing `[obj, obj, obj]` will make the list point to the same object three times, regardless of whether `obj` is mutable.  It's just that if `obj` is immutable, you probably won't notice the difference between three copies of the same object, and three different objects.  If the object is mutable, you can mutate it, and then you will see that you mutate all three list entries (if they all point to the same object), as opposed to just one (if you had made three separate objects).

Comment: @BrenBarn Ok, But this *is*  what I've said in the answer. You'll *never* notice the difference with ummutable object (that's why `['-'] * 10` is safe), unless you will check the object's identity, which is fine.

Comment: @Elazar can you explain how this `listBig[wordPosY][3:3+len(word)] = word` works? I don't understand what it is doing..

Comment: @digitalfarmer it replaces the part `listBig[wordPosY][3]` through `listBig[wordPosY][3+len(word)-1]` with a sub-list composed by the elements of the string `word`.

Comment: @Elazar is the 3:3 specific for this situation? how is that part determined? thanks

Comment: @digitalfarmer I am sorry I wrote it in a confusing way. It's not 3:3 anywhere. It's actually `listBig[wordPosY][ 3 : (3+len(word))]`

Answer (score 3):

Use the `list` constructor to make a shallow copy of `listSmall`

```
listBig = [list(listSmall) for i in range(3)]
```

The other equivalent (less readable IMO) way is using an empty slice:

```
listBig = [listSmall[:] for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: Or alternatively, `listSmall[:]`

Comment: @Volatility knew I would have to add that as well

Answer (score 1):

You want to make a copy of `listSmall` when you put it in `listBig`. You can do that using the `list` function:

```
listBig = [list(listSmall), list(listSmall), list(listSmall)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first and last list can still be shared. A more memory-efficient implementation is

```
listBig = [listSmall, listSmall[:], listSmall]
```

Notice that the 2nd one uses slice notation to create a copy of the entire `listSmall` list.