# Index Error: list index out of range (Python) -- Printing to Console

Tags: python, list, printing, console

I am having trouble following the error that I am getting which is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joelwilliams/Desktop/delete me", line 30, in <module>
    v.writef( '======================', 10, 10 )
  File "/Users/joelwilliams/Desktop/delete me", line 24, in writef
    self.write( word )
  File "/Users/joelwilliams/Desktop/delete me", line 15, in write
    self.l[ self.y ] [ self.x : ( self.x + len( word ) ) ] = word
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The main code is here:

```
class board():
    def __init__( self ):
        self.x, self.y = 0, 0
        self.l = []
        self.screenWidth, self.screenHeight = 0, 0

    def createBoard( self ):
        listBig = [ ['`'] * self.screenWidth for _ in range( self.screenHeight ) ]

    def setup( self, sw, sh ):
        self.screenWidth = sw - 1
        self.screenHeight = sh - 1

    def write( self, word ):
        self.l[ self.y ] [ self.x : ( self.x + len( word ) ) ] = word

    def draw( self ):
        for v in self.l:
            print(''.join(v))

    def writef( self, word, y, x ):
        self.cursorPosX = x - 1
        self.cursorPosY = y - 1
        self.write( word )

v = board()
v.setup( 75, 20 )
v.createBoard()

v.writef( '======================', 10, 10 )
v.writef( '=                    =', 11, 10 )
v.writef( '=   Pls Work.        =', 12, 10 )
v.writef( '=                    =', 13, 10 )
v.writef( '======================', 14, 10 )

v.draw()
```

The desired result is for the console to display:

```
           ======================
           =                    =
           =   Pls Work.        =
           =                    =
           ======================
```

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259925/making-a-list-independent-of-itself) as a guide to create the above code
thanks in advance!

Comment: I swear that this is the last question today :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `createBoard()` method:

```
def createBoard( self ):
    listBig = [ ['`'] * self.screenWidth for _ in range( self.screenHeight ) ]
```

You're creating a list of the right length and height, but you never assign it to `self.l`. So `self.l` is still a list of length 0.

Also, in your `write()` method:

```
def write( self, word ):
    self.l[ self.y ] [ self.x : ( self.x + len( word ) ) ] = word
```

It looks like you wanted `self.cursorPosX` (and Y) there instead of `self.x` and `self.y`.

Make those two changes, and your program should do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

- creates a board (now `self.l == []`)
- sets up the board over two function calls, one of which sets a function-local variable `bigList`; maybe you meant to set `self.l` (but still `self.l == []`)
- sets two instance variables `cursorPosX` and `cursorPosY` which are not referenced anywhere else; I'll assume you meant to set `x` and `y` (and still `self.l == []`)
- attempts to retrieve an element of an element of `self.l` (while `self.l == []`)

It would help if you actually initialized `self.l` somewhere. I suggest rolling `.__init__()`, `.setup()` and `.createBoard()` into one, and similarly with `.write()` and `.writef()`. Something like this::

```
class Board():
  def __init__(self, width, height):
    self.l = [['`'] * (width - 1) for _ in range(height - 1)]

  def write(self, text, x, y):
    dx = x + len(text)
    self.l[y][x:dx] = text

  def draw(self):
    for row in self.l:
      print(''.join(row))
```

Note that the useless member variables `screenWidth`, `screenHeight`, `x`, `y`, `cursorPosX`, and `cursorPosY` have all been eliminated.

To use this new code:

```
board = Board(75, 20)
board.write('======================', 10, 10)
board.write('=                    =', 11, 10)
board.write('=   Pls Work.        =', 12, 10)
board.write('=                    =', 13, 10)
board.write('======================', 14, 10)
board.draw()
```

Comment: I didn't notice all of those bugs.. Thanks for the help and showing a better way of making my program!